# My Answer was deleted even though helpful

Tags: support, deleted-questions

My answer to this question [What is this floating point effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088801/what-is-this-floating-points-effect) was deleted even though it was useful to people.

I know the reason that it was deleted was that I had not explained more on the link I provided. But I have edited it and made it a better answer . Since it was helpful to people shouldnt it be undeleted . After all thats what stackoverflow is all about right, helping others.

I am a fairly new user and Im getting adjusted here.I would prefer that my answer is undeleted. If not possible then please explain why.

Here is the answer.

> Well... that is a really big topic you are getting into . Developing it with basic javascript is not easy. Some Frameworks can help You 
>   Try Verlet [Verlet](http://subprotocol.com/system/introducing-verlet-js.html)

And my edit:

> Well... that is a really big topic you are getting into . Developing it with basic javascript is not easy. Some Frameworks can help You 
>   Try Verlet [Verlet](http://subprotocol.com/system/introducing-verlet-js.html)
>
> verlet-js is a light-weight physics engine, authored by Sub Protocol, which you can use in your web-based games.  As the name suggests, verlet-js is based on an iterative technique called Verlet integration used to calculate the behavior of objects in its two-dimensional world.
>
> Verlet integration is often used for the math behind putting particles in motion.In your case I believe that verlet can be used to develop that effect.
>
> Heres a small guide to get started with it [Getting started with verlet js](http://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-verlet-js/)

Comment: mind copying your edited answer here? not everyone can see it :)

Comment: @Patrice - it's pushing a library link:(

Comment: @MartinJames thank you! I assumed it was something of that nature, nice to have the confirmation :)

Comment: Contrary to reopening, there is no provision for undeleting edited answers. You could use a custom flag to ask a moderator to undelete it but, even with your modifications, that answer still only advertises a physics library, so the flag may very well be declined. If the question was good, I would suggest you add some code that demonstrates how the Velvet library can solve the questioner's problem... but the question is far from good in the first place.

Comment: The whole question has now been deleted, so problem solved.

Comment: the added text adds nothing... it sounds like a marketing description. If you wanted that link to stay up in an answer, you might have wanted to, like Bill the Lizard said, to include some code showing HOW to do it.

Comment: A small note: an answer being upvoted is not necessarily proof it is "useful" to people. It only means people think it is alright. In this case, probably because they are people who like the framework you link to.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedbacks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question you answered was entirely too broad. It's closed and is likely to be deleted if not extensively edited by the OP.

Your answer was little more than a link at the time that it was deleted by a moderator.

> Well... that is a really big topic you are getting into . Developing ist witch basic javascrip is not easy. Some Frameworks can help You Try Verlet Verlet

You edited it to improve it quite a bit the next day, but given the nature of the question I don't think it's worth undeleting.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback